# Find same href anchor on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, href, location-href

I want to find anchor tags with same hrefs on the current page

For example I have three anchor tags of same href on the current page like

```
<a href="https://www.link.com" class="btn btn-cta">
```

The class will be same for all the buttons.

Sorry i forgot to update my code which is updated

```
  $("a").each(function(){
               if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname){

               }
       });
```

Is there any better way of doing this.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry i forgot to add my code . Please check the question again

Comment: Just query for it? ```$(`a[href="${window.location.pathname}"`)``` the same way you'd use `$("a")` to find "all `<a>` elements"?

Comment: Why it is downvote?

Comment: Probably because if you know how to use jquery, you should know how to select "all matching elements".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this. find your elements using `$("[href='"+window.location.pathname+"']")` this method.

```js
var path = window.location.pathname;

$("a[href='"+path+"']").each(function(){
  //do your code here
  console.log(window.location.pathname);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.link.com" class="btn btn-cta">link1</a>
<a href="/js" class="btn btn-cta">link2</a>
<a href="/js" class="btn btn-cta">link3</a>
<a href="https://www.link.com" class="btn btn-cta">link4</a>
```

Comment: there are other elements with the `href` attribute, so at the very least, add the `a` in the selector, but probably also use a template literal instead of string concatenation.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the suggestions. code updated